# jQuery - Can't get listview anchor to trigger alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview

I've got a popup on page A which appends to (or creates, if it doesn't already exist) a listview on page B. After creating or appending to the listview, I call:

```
$('#summaryList').listview().listview('refresh');
```

In the listview on page B, there is an `a` within each `li`. The `a` 
opens up another popup. This is all working as expected. I'm trying to get an alert to fire when the `a` tag is clicked, but nothing seems to be working.

I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.editBtn').click(function( event ) {
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

as well as

```
$("a.editBtn").on('pagecreate', function() {
    alert("test");
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is 'pagecreate' ? try putting 'click' instead of 'pagecreate'

Comment: You're assigning the click event before the a.editBtn has been generated

Comment: @freedomn-m, that link to [Event binding on dynamically created elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) worked perfectly! Thanks!